# Android scale imageview around its center

Tags: android

This should be the simplest thing. I'm trying to use a ViewPropertyAnimator to scale an ImageView around its center.

I've got the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/target"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/crosshair"
    />
```

Then I have the following code:

```
// Now we show the burst view
                if(mLastBurst != null)
                {
                    ((FrameLayout)(mLastBurst.getParent())).removeView(mLastBurst);
                    mLastBurst.animate().cancel();
                    mLastBurst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                mLastBurst = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.target, null);
                mLastBurst.setX(event.getX()-mLastBurst.getWidth()/2);
                mLastBurst.setY(event.getY()-mLastBurst.getHeight()/2);
                mLastBurst.setPivotX(50);
                mLastBurst.setPivotY(50);
                mLastBurst.animate().scaleXBy(10).scaleYBy(10).setDuration(500);
                addContentView(mLastBurst,new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

When I run the code all that happens is that rather than scaling the image around the center of the image, the image drifts over to the left.

I've played with the pivotX and pivotY values to no avail. This should be simple and I guess I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to set pivotX and or pivotY, they are centered by default. If you set them I believe that the unit is pixels.

Comment: Are the dimensions known when you ask for width and height? And maybe the content view is treated differently compared to other views. Try using another container.